# How do I use the "referenced_tweets.type" response field in the Twitter API in Python code where I'm trying to extract Twitter hashtag data?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I am using code which is working fine. I have added the whole code as taken from geeks for geeks. But I want to modify it to add `referenced_tweets.type`. I am new to APIs and really want to understand how to fix this.

```
import pandas as pd
import tweepy


# function to display data of each tweet
def printtweetdata(n, ith_tweet):
    print()
    print(f"Tweet {n}:")
    print(f"Username:{ith_tweet[0]}")
    print(f"likes:{ith_tweet[1]}")
    print(f"Location:{ith_tweet[2]}")
    print(f"Following Count:{ith_tweet[3]}")
    print(f"Follower Count:{ith_tweet[4]}")
    print(f"Total Tweets:{ith_tweet[5]}")
    print(f"Retweet Count:{ith_tweet[6]}")
    print(f"Tweet Text:{ith_tweet[7]}")
    print(f"Hashtags Used:{ith_tweet[8]}")


# function to perform data extraction
def scrape(words, date_since, numtweet):

    # Creating DataFrame using pandas
    db = pd.DataFrame(columns=['username', 'likes', 'location', 'following',
                            'followers', 'totaltweets', 'retweetcount', 'text', 'hashtags'])

    # We are using .Cursor() to search through twitter for the required tweets.
    # The number of tweets can be restricted using .items(number of tweets)
    tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=words, lang="en",
                        since=date_since, tweet_mode='extended').items(numtweet)

    # .Cursor() returns an iterable object. Each item in
    # the iterator has various attributes that you can access to
    # get information about each tweet
    list_tweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets]

    # Counter to maintain Tweet Count
    i = 1

    # we will iterate over each tweet in the list for extracting information about each tweet
    for tweet in list_tweets:
        username = tweet.user.screen_name
        likes = tweet.favorite_count
        location = tweet.user.location
        following = tweet.user.friends_count
        followers = tweet.user.followers_count
        totaltweets = tweet.user.statuses_count
        retweetcount = tweet.retweet_count
        hashtags = tweet.entities['hashtags']

        # Retweets can be distinguished by a retweeted_status attribute,
        # in case it is an invalid reference, except block will be executed
        try:
            text = tweet.retweeted_status.full_text
        except AttributeError:
            text = tweet.full_text
        hashtext = list()
        for j in range(0, len(hashtags)):
            hashtext.append(hashtags[j]['text'])

        # Here we are appending all the extracted information in the DataFrame
        ith_tweet = [username, likes, location, following,
                    followers, totaltweets, retweetcount, text, hashtext]
        db.loc[len(db)] = ith_tweet

        # Function call to print tweet data on screen
        printtweetdata(i, ith_tweet)
        i = i+1
    filename = 'etihad.csv'

    # we will save our database as a CSV file.
    db.to_csv(filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Enter your own credentials obtained
    # from your developer account
    consumer_key = 
    consumer_secret = 
    access_key = 
    access_secret = 
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    # Enter Hashtag and initial date
    print("Enter Twitter HashTag to search for")
    words = input()
    print("Enter Date since The Tweets are required in yyyy-mm--dd")
    date_since = input()

    # number of tweets you want to extract in one run
    numtweet = 100
    scrape(words, date_since, numtweet)
    print('Scraping has completed!')
```

I now want to add `referenced_tweets.type` in order to get if the Tweet is a Retweet or not but I'm not sure how to do it. Can someone help?

Comment: What is `tweet`? How are you retrieving it?

Comment: Hi ive added the code for your reference pls have a look, thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`API.search`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#tweepy.API.search) uses the [standard search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets), part of Twitter API v1.1.
`referenced_tweets` is a value that can be set for `tweet.fields`, a Twitter API v2 [fields](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/fields) parameter.

Currently, if you want to use Twitter API v2 through Tweepy, you'll have to use the development version of Tweepy on the master branch and its [`Client`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html) class. Otherwise, you'll need to wait until Tweepy v4.0 is released.

Alternatively, if your only goal is to determine whether a [Status](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html#tweepy.models.Status)/[Tweet object](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet) is a Retweet or not, you can simply check for the `retweeted_status` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, could you suggest how? im getting an error saying the status attribute does not exist.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You should probably ask a new question with what you're trying to do, the code your using, and the full traceback you're encountering.